# Make changes to a file (sed, awk)

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to clean up the next file:

```
1. 10.160.120.10 ; 140.0.0.40 ;Data-- 1155~00120~xtl~12/01/2016  03:00:24~000BBBBBA4FB~ÍežG5„È&gÈe@Ÿ#•Œ‘„¦åEI²6frÞõ+ã:®*ÓÓÂ"ða5»V$è~
2. ¼?Amµxðïej£„7‹ìËÏð‡.4 --
3. 10.160.120.11 ; 140.10.10.10 ;Data-- 1155~00120~xtl~12/01/2016  03:00:54~2B3BB1EB1BBB~£ˆD]†CÀ,£ÑÉ»In&Ry+/jÑ%A¡ã ÷d_#C÷—NÏÕÞ
3. Ü‚úè"åD\’c\ûñ7x°yFÃ¦ï --
```

Note that the numbers are not an actual part of the file. They are just reference for the number of line. The size of the line depends on the encoded message (That is why the 3 is reapeated because it basically one line). There are thousands of records but they follow the same pattern. Each record ends with a (--).

Basically what I am trying to achive is to just get the IPs side by side.

For example:

```
10.160.120.10  000BBBBBA4FB
```

My first step would be to delete everything between the first (;) and the fourth (~) since that pattern is the same for each record.

Which leads me to this.

```
sed 's/;.*~//'
```

However this particular command would delete everything untill the last (~) and not the fourth.

If it succesfully removes everything between the first (;) and the fourth (~) it would get me something like this:

0.165.65.113 0008B9A4F3~ÍežG5„È&gÈe@Ÿ#•Œ‘„¦åEI²6frÞõ+ã:®*ÓÓÂ"ða5»V$è~
¼?Amµxðïej£„7‹ìËÏð‡.4 --

And then I guess I could delete everything after the first (~) so I can get the desired output.

Am I following the right procedure? Should I achive this with swd or awk? Any suggestion are appreciated!

Comment: If you want to delete to the next tilde, use `[^~]*~` instead of `.*~`. To the second tilde, `[^~]*~[^~]*~`, etc.

Comment: Yes, this was helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to remove stuff, why don't you just keep the stuff you want?

```
sed -r -n 's/^[^0-9]*(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).*([0-9A-F]{12}).*$/\1 \3/p'
#                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                    IP Address                     12 Hex digits
```

Explanation:

1. `\1 \3` means enter everything that matched the first and the third set of parenthesis of the search term.
2. `^[^0-9]*` matches all non-digits from the beginning of the file
3. `([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}` matches an IP address. The whole term is in parentheses because we want to keep it. The inner `(...)` could be referenced as `\2` in the replacement term, but we don't need that.
4. `[0-9A-F]{12}` is simply 12 hexadecimal digits (upper case, use `[0-9a-fA-F] if you expect lower cases as well)

Comment: Oh, never though of that lol! But yes, this certainly works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data struture is the same

use several field separator at once with a class including ";" and "~". Be carefull , not space alone as separator like by default that return a different field 3 (and 6)

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]*[;~][[:blank:]]*' '/--$/ {print $1 " " $7}' YourFile
```

Assuming there is only space char and no tab as separator and data line have Data

```
awk -F ' *[;~] *' '/--$/ {print $1 " " $7}' YourFile
```